# writing a .bat file to change a user password on certain dates

Tags: windows, batch-file, passwords, cmd

HI I am tring to remember how to write a .bat file to run on certain date to change a user's password automaticly. The way I have tried is.
@echo off
date \t 
(if system date is 01/07/13) go to line 15
(if system date is 01/22/13) go to line 16
(if system date is 02/05/13) go to line 17
(if system date is 02/17/13) go to line 18
(if system date is 02/27/13) go to line 19

net user user password
net user user password3
net user user password4
net user user password5
net user user password6

Can Anyone help me out

Ok I need more help please I have tried this both ways and I can not seem to get this to work can anyone help me out
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten this to just

```
if %date%==01/07/13 net user user password
```

That's much shorter than having a label and a `goto` for every one.

Comment: It should look like `if 01/23/2013==01/23/2013 goto :line15`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `gotos` with labels.

Labels are made with `:LABELNAME`. Gotos are `goto :LABELNAME`.

Use [this method](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/956/windows-batch-file-bat-to-get-current-date-in-mmddyyyy-format/) to fetch the date--adapt it to return the date in the format you want. Use:

```
if %date%=="date/to/test" goto :LINE15

rem ...

:LINE15
net user user password2
```

Also, use `exit` or `goto :EOF` to end the batch file after each *password change* and after the *main program* (with the `if` tests). If not, the program will "fall through" to each `net user` statement and change the password several times until it becomes `password6`--obviously undesirable.

Hope this helps!!